# How to grep a multiple pattern per line

Tags: grep

```
lot:1, callback:0, header:x, parse:x,
lot:2, callback:0, header:y, parse:x,
lot:3, callback:0, header:x, parse:x,
lot:4, callback:0, header:x, parse:x,
lot:5, callback:0, header:y, parse:x,
```

Tried `grep -e "lot:" -e "header:"`
but it only highlights the -e pattern.

Expected output should be

```
lot:1, header:x,
lot:2, header:y,
lot:3, header:x,
lot:4, header:x,
lot:5, header:y,
```

Comment: This works for me: `grep -e "lot:[0-9]*" -e "header:\w*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try:

```
grep 'lot:.*header:'
```

This will list all lines containing `lot:........header:....`

If you want to get exact the output you posted in question, you can turn to awk:

```
awk -F', ' '$1~/^lot:/ && $3~/^header:/{print $1 FS $3}' file
```